# when I execute linked list using class it shows an extra zero

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, output, execution

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Node {
    public :
    int data;
    Node *next;

    Node()
    {
        data = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
    Node (int a)
    {   data = a;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
void push(Node **head_ref , int n)
{  
    Node *new_node = new Node();
    new_node -> data = n;
    new_node -> next = *head_ref;
    *head_ref = new_node;}

void display(Node *head_ref)
{ while(head_ref != NULL)
    {
        cout << head_ref -> data << " ";
        head_ref = head_ref-> next;
    }
}
int main()
{   Node *head = new Node();
    push (&head  ,1 );
    push(&head ,0 );
    push(&head , 1);
    display(head);
    return(9);}
```

This when executed returns 1 0 1 0 as output  , First i thought it is because of constructors but later I came to know that it is not something causing the problem.

Comment: This program creates four nodes - one in `main`, and three more in three `push` calls. So of course it prints four integers.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is a very, very expensive way to get `<iostream>`. You're including the entire C++ standard library to get one file. That's slowing your program's build times by whole orders of magnitude and cluttering the program with tens of thousands of identifiers you aren't using. Kinda like dropping a nuclear bomb on a city to kill one bad guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node *head = new Node();
```

Creates the extra node. Instead use

```
Node *head = nullptr;
```

or, if using an older compiler,

```
Node *head = NULL;
```

to point `head` at a safe location until legitimate nodes are added.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
Node *head = new Node();
```

Creates a new Node, the first one, then the other 3 nodes are created by calling the `push()` thrice.

Workaround? After pushing the values, do `head = head->next`

Comment: That leaks the initial node. Better to never create that bogus node in the first place with `Node *head = nullptr;`

Comment: can you please rewrite my code with the changes you are suggesting.